# how to hide an accordion pane in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello I have been looking for a good accordion for a long time.
I finally found a model that I like.
The only small concern is that I would like when I open my page with the accordion
Let the first part be hidden like the two below
when the page loads

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you already have `$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();` that will hide all the answer except the first one. So you just change the selector to hide what you wish to.. or just add `display: none` to the elements you wish to hide

Comment: So `$("#faq_slide .answer").hide();` is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line
`$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide()`
to:
`$("#faq_slide .answer").hide()`

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Remove the `.not(":first")` from `$("#faq_slide .answer").not(":first").hide();` because that part selects all the elements except the first.

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean all of them should be closed initially?
Remove the `.not(":first")` from the first line.

```
$("#faq_slide .answer").hide()
```

```js
$("#faq_slide .answer").hide();
$("#faq_slide .question").click(function() {
  if ($(this).next(".answer").is(":visible")) {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideUp(300);
  } else {
    $(this).next(".answer").slideDown(300).siblings(".answer").slideUp(300);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
}

.question {
  color: #555;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #efefef;
}

.question:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
  color: #777;
  padding: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 13px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<div id="faq_slide">
  <div class="question">First Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Second Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="question">Third Question</div>
  <div class="answer">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```